# Strange update statement behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

Executing the following query

```
UPDATE tbl_outcome SET  `type` = 'do', `statement` = 'NAREs, private sector organizations and NGOs develop innovation platforms, disseminate  market information to processors and develop their marketing skills', 
`actionsite_id` = 440, `code` = 'G&T-I' WHERE (outcome_id = '546');
```

will cause this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
 1062 Duplicate entry 'NAREs, private sector organizations and NGOs develop innovation ' for key 'statement'
```

noting that there is another row shares the same statement value but why it rejects the duplication

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_outcome` (
      `outcome_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `statement` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `actionsite_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`outcome_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `statement` (`statement`,`actionsite_id`),
      KEY `actionsite_id` (`actionsite_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `tbl_outcome_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`actionsite_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_actionsite` (`actionsite_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=551 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

mysql> mysql> SELECT statement FROM crpcoreix.tbl_outcome limit 5;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| statement                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Female and male farmers/shakeholders use/adopt/implement methods/tools/approaches/technologies/NRMpractices/Varieties/framework/concepts                                                                                            |
|   Female and male farmers/stakeholders (inc.youth) awareness, skills and knowledge increased                                                                                                                                          |
|   Female and male farmers/stakeholders (inc.youth) awareness, skills and knowledge increased                                                                                                                                          |
|   Interventions better targeted/prioritized by stakeholders                                                                                                                                                                           |
|  At least (3-15?) potato candidate varieties (short season, heat tolerant, and pest/disease resistant) compatible  with cereal crops: identified and recommended for release in at least  three countries (China, Bangladesh, India) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `UNIQUE KEY `statement` (`statement`,`actionsite_id`),`

Comment: OMG, workbench didnt marked UQ for statment field thank you @SatwikNadkarny

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a unique Key constraint on the `Statement` column named :

```
UNIQUE KEY `statement` (`statement`,`actionsite_id`),
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: but why workbench is not marking it as unique and also there is so many rows holds duplicated data ?

Comment: @SuhaybKharabsheh Could you share data from the table so we can reproduce the exact scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_outcome
```

This will give you index_name for the Unique key

then run following query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_outcome DROP INDEX index_name
```

This will delete Unique key constraint

Comment: Or if you are using workbench then click on table setting and click on 2nd tab (Indexes) there it will show you Unique key constraint

Comment: statement index has unique type with tow indexes associated statement and actionsite_id, removing this will cause error since there is already duplicated data